# Causes becoming "numb"?

Tags: word-usage

In the following sentence I want to use the word "numb" in a metaphorical way:
"All causes became numb"
Meaning, causes couldn't help the person who ended up in a certain situation. Is it possible to use this word like this?

The content is religious and contains lots of metaphors...
A summary of the well-known story of Jonah:
He was cast into the sea and swallowed by a large fish. The sea was stormy, the night was turbulent and dark, and in an allround hopeless state, the supplication: “There is no God but You, Glory to You; surely I became one of the wrongdoers!” swiftly became his means of salvation. The following unravels the astonishing mystery of this supplication:
Under those circumstances all causes became numb. For to rescue him in that state, there was a need for an Entity Who could subject the fish, the sea, the night and the sky to His Command.

Comment: Bdy: you must give more context in your example. As it appears, "causes" seems to be the wrong word.

Comment: Updated the question with more context.

Comment: Did you write this summary or is it pre written? If you wrote  it I would not use it as the meaning is entirely unclear, but if it’s not, then I guess I’m just missing the link? Either way I don’t think this is right because it isn’t clear what “causes” are.

Comment: It's not clear what causes mean, or what "all causes became numb" means - please try and explain clearly what you are trying to say by that specific sentence, what you mean by "causes" and what you mean by "numb". "Cause" is a word with many shades of meaning: a political cause; a purpose or reason; an event that is necessarily followed by another event; etc.

Comment: Of course, the use of the word "numb" is quite apt--and powerful, too. Don

Comment: Only people become numb or parts of them, not things. *I was numbed by the cause*. Or: The cause left me numb. Or even: The cause numbed me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context you give is written in almost archaic English. I doubt that its intended meaning would be properly understood today except perhaps those who think in a Christian religious context and firmly believe that God understands only Early Modern English.

Cause(s) is an awkward word to use in the context that you have given

You are trying to use it in the sense of someone who causes things

(OED)

> **Cause** (n) **2. A person or other agent who brings about or occasions something,** with or without intention. (Often in bad sense: one who occasions, or is to blame for mischief, misfortune, etc.)
>
> 1713   G. Berkeley Three Dialogues Hylas & Philonous ii. 80   *God is the supreme and Universal Cause of all Things.*

This use is rare. Usually "a cause" is understood as a political or philosophical principle or institution.

And you will see that **numb** is not quite right either.

> Numb (adj.) b. In extended use: **as if deprived of** physical sensation or **the power of movement**; (in later use) (chiefly) spec. emotionally deadened, unresponsive, or spent, as the result of grief, shock, fear, etc. rare before 19th cent.

But this is not the common use of "numb" which usually means "lacking the ability to experience the sensation of touch."

*"It's very cold out there! My fingers are numb."*

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, I don’t think so. The reason is not because a ‘cause’ couldn’t become ‘numb’ in a metaphorical sense (e.g. a revolution dying because the problem It was revolting against was removed) but because I don’t think you’re using the word ‘cause’ correctly.
A cause cannot help a person in the manner you’re suggesting, and it isn’t clear to me what exactly your intended meaning was, but my answer still stands - in this context, no, that phrase does not work.

Comment: I just love it when people just say it without getting into the weeds. Also, for questions like this, relying on one's internalized language knowledge is enough in my opinion. +1